# Google Drive issue when trying to download many times

Tags: indy, drive, idhttp

I have problem using Indy's `TIdHTTP` in my Windows app created with C++Builder XE7.

I am doing a simple task... when my app launches, it goes to a link with a direct download and the app begins to download.

All works great, but when I do many requests to download (it is a simple `.txt` file) from Google Drive, I get an `"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"` error.

I tried many ways (change the `User-Agent`, memory leakage control, etc) without luck.

Can somebody give me an idea of what the problem may be?

Comment: You are likely exceeding Google's limits on how often the file can be accessed. You need to examine the data provided with the `403` response to differentiate the exact reason. See [Resolve errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors) in Google's Drive API documentation. There are many different reasons that Google issues a `403` error.

Comment: Thank You Remy for your answer. There are some way to avoid such limits?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? It explains the various limits and what to do about them.

Comment: Thank you Remy. Issue was Google's limits.